# get Learndash course Author Id From Course id

Tags: wordpress

I am using learn-dash with WordPress. It creates courses as custom post type. How can I get course author id if I have only `$course_id`?

I've tried this:

```
$author_id=$post->post_author;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the course ID, you can get the whole post ('sfwd-courses' post type in this case):

$course = get_post($course_id);

$author_id = $course->post_author;

Hope this help.